# cuda and cublas segmentation fault

Tags: cuda, cublas

In my main.cpp I am creating some vectors on host, then copying them on the device. I also create a cublas handle because I want to use cublas :

```
#define N 3
int main() {
  float a[N], b[N], c[N];
  float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
  // allocate the memory on the GPU
  cudaMalloc( &dev_a, N * sizeof(float) ) ;
  cudaMalloc( &dev_b, N * sizeof(float) );
  cudaMalloc( &dev_c, N * sizeof(float) );
  // fill the arrays 'a' and 'b' on the CPU
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    a[i] = i+0.1;
    b[i] = i*i+0.5;
    printf( "%f + %f \n", a[i], b[i]);
  }
  cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
  cudaMemcpy( dev_b, b, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

 gpu_blas_sum(handle, dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, N) ;
 // copy the array 'c' back from the GPU to the CPU
 cudaMemcpy( c, dev_c, N * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

 // ... Free cublas memory 
}
```

Then I have a cuda.cu and cuda.h files in order to call `gpu_blas_sum` in the code above on the device

cuda.h

```
void gpu_blas_sum(cublasHandle_t &handle,  float *A,  float *B, float *C,  int n) ;
```

cuda.cu

```
void gpu_blas_sum(cublasHandle_t &handle, float *A, float *B, float *C, int n) {
  const float alf = 1;
  A[0] = 3;
  cublasScopy(handle,n,A,1,C,1);//C = A
  cublasSaxpy(handle,n,&alf,B,1,C,1);
}
```

The line `A[0] = 3` in cublas.cu results in a segmentation fault. I guess then that my function gpu_blas_sum is considered as a host function.

How can I make it execute on device so that I can dereference device pointers, and take advantage of GPU speed when I use cublas functions?

Thanks for help

Comment: You must write kernels if you want to run code on the GPU (or device functors if you use something like thrust). A kernel *could* (on a supported GPU) use the CUBLAS device API. If you are trying to ask how to write a kernel, I think you have come to the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks Talonmies. I know how to write kernels. So if I understand you well, I have to transform gpu_blas_sum into a kernel, create a c++ function as a wrapper that launches the kernel with one block and one thread, and let cublas automatically optimize by launching many threads and blocks under the hoods?

Comment: That would seem like a huge waste of effort (and latency penalties) compared with just calling the CUBLAS APIs directly from the host. I still don't understand what the problem here is. You try to access a device pointer on the host and it fails. Surely the solution is just not to try and access the device pointer on the host in the first place?

Comment: I see that the simplified version of my problem make my question weird. My problem is I have 10 matrices A1 ... A10 and an input vector X and 10 functions h1 .. h10. I want to calculate A1*X, then apply h1 to the resulting vector. so X2 = h1(A1*X), then continue with X3=h2(A2*X2) etc... My matrices are created once and for all on the device, and my functions h1 .. h10 are coded as kernels. So I want to execute A1*X directly on the device, so that the result is on the device, and I directly apply the kernel h1 on it and pass it to the next step

Comment: Please update your question with what you are actually trying to do here and some code which illustrates it, preferably something that might be compileable for others to experiment with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is illegal:

```
A[0] = 3;
```

This is *host* code, but `A` is a *device* pointer.  Basic cuda rules are that host code is not allowed to dereference a device pointer, and device code is not allowed to dereference a host pointer.  If you dereference a device pointer in host code, a seg fault is the likely outcome (just as if you dereferenced any other pointer that was meaningless in host code, such as a NULL pointer).

If you really want to do *this specific* operation, just as you have written, then a tedious but workable solution would be:

```
float my_val = 3;
cudaMemcpy(A, &my_val, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

If you want to move everything to the device, I suggest you study a cuda sample code that calls cublas functions from the device, such as [simpleDevLibCUBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpledevlibcublas-gpu-device-api-library-functions--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-)

Comment: Thanks Robert. My current architecture does not unfortunately support DevLibCublas. Can you please confirm that the normal cublas, when called from host, is indeed executed on device? So the gain of speed realized with DevLibCublas would be the overhead of the call. Can you please give an estimation of that time?

Comment: Yes, the normal cublas, when called from the host, is indeed executed on the device.